# How do I use a callback to fetch data from mysql with node.js and ejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I need to fetch `foo` from the query below:

```
exports.get = function(id, cb) {
    sql = 'SELECT `sidebar`, `test` FROM users WHERE `id` = "' + id + '"';
    con.query(sql, function(err, foo) {
      if (err) { return cb(err) }
      else { return cb(foo) };
    });
}
```

Then render `foo` on my app.js like this:

```
app.get('/dashboard', ensureLoggedIn('/login'),
  function(req, res) {
    const id = req.session.passport.user;
    const foo = db.defaults.set(id) //db.defaults.set calls the query
    console.log(foo); //prints undefined
    res.render('dashboard', { foo:foo });
});
```

This was my latest attempt:

```
app.get('/dashboard', ensureLoggedIn('/login'),
  function(req, res, next) {
    const id = req.session.passport.user;
    db.defaults.get(id, function(err, foo) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.render('dashboard', {foo:foo});
      //also tried:
      //return res.render('dashboard', {foo:foo});
    });
```

The attempt above doesn't render the page at all.  The html loads as:

```
[object object]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to render server side a template asynchronously (after fetching the data) and you can't do that.

What you can do is send synchronously the template to the client and then expose an endpoint to fetch those data and modify the page accordingly (on the client).

```
app.get('/dashboard', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), function(req, res) {
  res.render('dashboard');
});

app.get('/fetchdata', function (req, res, next) {
  const id = req.session.passport.user;
    db.defaults.get(id, function(err, foo) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.send(foo);
    });
})
```

Comment: What would the endpoint for `/fetchdata` look like on dashboard.ejs?

Comment: you need to remove the foo parameter on the .ejs file cause that won't work, you can make the api call to /fetchdata in your js after the page has loaded.